# Computing a simple statement with 4 arithmetic operators doesn't work

Tags: c#, list, for-loop

I am trying to learn c# and I currently I'm trying to make a calculator where you can type in however many characters you want and it'll show you the final result...

For my example i will use `List<string> Statement = {"12", "/", "4", "*", "3"}`

```
string numbers = "0123456789";

for (int i = 0; i < Statement.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!numbers.Contains(Statement[i][0]))
                {
                    Statement[i] = Convert.ToString(Operations.Compute(Convert.ToInt32(Statement[i - 1]), Convert.ToInt32(Statement[i + 1]), Statement[i]));
                    Statement.RemoveAt(i - 1);
                    Statement.RemoveAt(i + 1);
                    i--;
                }
            }
```

Operations compute:

```
class Operations
    {
        public static float Compute(float num1, float num2, string OpType)
        {
            if(OpType == "+") { return num1 + num2; }
            if(OpType == "-") { return num1 - num2; }
            if(OpType == "*") { return num1 * num2; }
            if(OpType == "/") { return num1 / num2; }

            return 0;
        }
    }
```

When I run the program and list all elements from `Statement` with a simple `foreach` loop I expect it to return 9(since 12/4*3 = 9).

Instead it lists the following three numbers: 3, 4, 3

It seems to always compute the first two numbers and then list the rest.

Comment: If you call a `RemoveAt` then your `i` is no longer the same index of the value it was before. Which means your second `RemoveAt` removes something else

Comment: You do it in a very complex way. Maybe a `Stack<>` or a `Queue<>` can help you. Then you dont need the `for`-loop.

Comment: @Neijwiert I knew RemoveAt would effect i somehow, didn't think about that one. Thanks!

Comment: The first time `Statement.RemoveAt(i + 1);` is exectued, i is 1, so you remove item[2], which _at that moment_ is `"*"`.

Comment: @oerkelens yeah i just changed that i + 1 in RemoveAt to just i and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to compute the formula, I suggest using stack machine. In *general case* you have to convert the initial formula into **RPN** (Reverse Polish Notation) with a help of [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).
However, if you have just `4` *infix binary* arithmetic operations you can put computation as

```
  // Let's extract the model: all possible infix binary operations
  Dictionary<string, Func<double, double, double>> operations = 
    new Dictionary<string, Func<double, double, double>>() {
      { "+", (x, y) => x + y },
      { "-", (x, y) => x - y },
      { "*", (x, y) => x * y },
      { "/", (x, y) => x / y },
  };

  List<string> data = new List<string>() {
    "12", "/", "4", "*", "3"
  };

  // Stack for data
  Stack<double> items = new Stack<double>();
  // Stack for operations
  Stack<Func<double, double, double>> ops = new Stack<Func<double, double, double>>();

  foreach (string item in data)
    if (double.TryParse(item, out double v)) // do we have number? 
      if (ops.Any()) // do we have an operation? 
        // if yes, execute it; put the outcome on the stack 
        items.Push(ops.Pop()(items.Pop(), v)); 
      else
        // if no operation, just put item on the stack
        items.Push(v);
    else // operation should be put on its stack
      ops.Push(operations[item]);

  double result = items.Pop();
```

Comment: Thank you for this in depth answer very much. I will look into what all of those mean.  And go one by one in my code to see how it affects everything.

Answer (score 0):

I just switched from `Statement.RemoveAt(i + 1);` to `Statement.RemoveAt(i);` and it works.

That's because when you do `Statement.RemoveAt(i - 1);` the position of i changes and so `Statement.RemoveAt(i + 1);` removes the element after the element you actually want to remove. Thank you for your help!